# .htm re-write is adding an ending / to my URL bar

Tags: url-rewriting

The client site I am working on required me to make the Page post type pages to end with the .htm extension.

I got that working, however when you go to a page...

`www.domain.com/mypage.htm` it loads the page but it then add an ending `/` to the URL in the address bar so it turns into this `www.domain.com/mypage.htm/` my client is asking me if I can disable this.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Settings->Permalinks and remove the trailing slash from your Custom Structure.